# How to trigger compute on one2many odoo 13

Tags: javascript, python, xml, odoo, odoo-13

Below is my code :
I've also tried putting inverse field but that also didn't worked. Also i cannot make another class that inherits sale.order as this is transient model, so that doesn't work. Please help, i am new to odoo.

```
class WizardDraft(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'wizard.draft'

    sale_order_lines =  fields.One2many('sale.order', compute="_compute_sale_orders")

    @api.model
    def _compute_sale_orders(self):
        self.sale_order_lines = self.env['sale.order'].search([('state', '=', 'draft')])
```

Answer (score 1):

> You cannot use One2Many relation of Models(models.Model) in Transient
>   Model(models.TransientModel)  because Transient model stores data
>   temporarily and it flushes out. So Many2one you create in Transient
>   Model is not a good idea.

So in this case, you can use Many2many of Model(sale.order) in Transient model(wizard.draft) and make it compute field.

```
class WizardDraft(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'wizard.draft'

    sale_order_lines =  fields.Many2many('sale.order', compute="_compute_sale_orders")

    @api.model
    def _compute_sale_orders(self):
        self.sale_order_lines = self.env['sale.order'].search([('state', '=', 'draft')])
```